# iTunes Connect app description text won't accept line breaks, description squished

Tags: iphone, submit, distribution, app-store-connect

What gives? I've tried multiple browsers, using safari on a mac.... the description text will NOT take any returns / line feeds, they just get stripped out. It doesn't matter if you cut/paste the description in the description form box, or write your own, everything gets stripped of line feeds and it ends up looking like a wall of text.

Has anyone seen this?? Is this normal? I don't want a description to hit the store like that...

Answer (score 2):

It looks this way on iTunes Connect but the formatting is respected on the AppStore.

Answer (score 0):

Hit the 'Edit' tab next to Metadata to edit the listing.

Comment: When editing it, it shows normally (with line breaks). When not editing and looking at their summary screen, there are no line breaks.